# jquery and java communication

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have jquery pop form to upload a file, after on submit (the page refresh and the pop close) i check something about the file and then if there's something wrong i need to pop up that form again (from the java code?), how could i do that ?

Comment: Maybe do your form validation with jQuery? You could also use AJAX to send your form data to your processing file, which could then return a number (or JSON) if there were any errors. This way there's no page reloads and your "pop up form" stays up at all times until the submit is successful.

Comment: What type of validation u have to perform,generally it can be categorized in two ways Server side and client side,both demand different logics

Comment: u are getting good response as well as queries related to your question but unfortunately response is not too good.

Comment: thank you @sam and others , im doing a server side check for the file the problem is when i upload the file and hit submit , the page refresh and the pop-up close by it self and i want to make the pop-up appear again after page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ( or must be using)  ajax in jquery with a popup.
When the user hits "submit", control goes to server side code.
The code runs to upload the file.
Whatever the result of upload (success/failure), that message is sent to the popup with ajax automatically.
In case, there is problem in uploading the file then, along with the failure message, you can send in the div which contains your form.

I think rather than refreshing the page to close the popup, allow the user to close the popup with close button.

Answer (score 0):

When "something is wrong" the server-side code (this applies to any language) should include within the HTML content Javascript that will trigger the "form" to be displayed again.

Comment: I guess you are trying to refer success and failure blocks in AJAX?

Comment: What I am saying is that if you want the client to act on an error, you need to have the response from the server indicate the error. Whether or not the error is handled with a success/failure block in Javascript depends on if the form is being submitted via AJAX or a regular browser POST - the original question doesn't state this.

Comment: Exactly this I was trying to ask,very well said ,client side should always be indicated about success or failure

Answer (score 0):

As I feel dizzy presently,can't write the code,but will try to break whole procedure in multiple steps:-

1. On Trigger(by some event) a pop up form will open from submission,which will have a button which will be calling a `OnClick Event`,which will be containing an Ajax call for client server communication
2. till the response don't `close or fade out` the Pop up box.
3. from server expect two tags `SUCCESS` or `ERROR` 
         a) On SUCCESS, remove form `DIV` and fade out/close the pop up
   with a success message b)On Error,display a refreshed form `DIV`

And so on